# Site not picking up CSS styles when LIVE

Tags: web-server, permissions, asp.net, web-hosting, css

I am using ASP.NET 3.5.

For some reason when I apply CSS to my controls on my plain form it shows in Visual Studio and it does work fine.

But for some reason when I make my site LIVE none of the styles are working.

Can this be a server issue? Some setting that must be changed?

When I put the full URL in of the CSS like below the CSS does not even comes up.

> http://www.example.com/CSS/global.css

Comment: **When I put the full URL in of the CSS like below the CSS does not even comes up.** so what happens instead? Do you get an error in the browser? What do the logs on the IIS server show?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your html site actually references the correct CSS file...

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" title="Default" href="css/global.css">
```

You should also try renaming it to "default.css"

Comment: Well my reference to the CSS does work on another domain in the Application Pool, something tells me that there is a problem in my current site settings in IIS, I just don't know what it can be...

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure exactly what to tell you now, sorry.